# Change mat-select-arrow icon

Tags: angular

How can I change the mat-select-arrow to another icon, besides the default dropdown?

I've tried various iterations of

```
.mat-select-arrow {
    icon: url('/assets/images/keyboard_arrow_down.png');
    content: icon;
}
```

Chrome developer tool's compute window does not seem to list any property that corresponds to the arrow type.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

assume you are using this:

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

The Arrow here is made with pure css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-select-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid;
    margin: 0 4px;
}
```

to changes this, override the border values and set a background-image

Edit: add `::ng-deep`; see comment from @Ruben Szekér

Edit 25.07.2023:
change the example code to `mat-mdc-select-arrow`

Comment: When overriding the CSS make sure to use the `::ng-deep` selector before the `.mat-select-arrow` class selector. [More information about the ::ng-deep selector](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Comment: The arrow is pure css, so if you want only delete the icon, you can set `border: none` in `.mat-select-arrow` css class

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to override the class "mat-mdc-select-arrow". Maybe things have changed in the past few years?

Comment: @JohnGilmer yes, you are right. I think it happened in this change: https://github.com/angular/components/commit/bf6f38abd7b8f115413aa9de08b632b017827ba9

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, I solved by following this procedure.

1. At first, I hide the mat-arrow by adding below this line of .css into component.css

   ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
   opacity: 0;
   }
2. And then, I have added the matIcon after the matselect but inside the MatFormField.

   ```
   <mat-icon matSuffix>domain</mat-icon>
   ```

or. You can add your custom Icon URL image by adding the border-images-source

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I had to set the 'border-image-source' property.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
    border-left: 15px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent !important;
    border-image-source: url('my img url') !important;
    border-image-repeat: stretch !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to achieve the custom css for angular material:

**Method 1) By disabling `viewencapsulation`:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, **ViewEncapsulation** } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-component',
  templateUrl: './sample-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-component.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  // *** This line disables the view encapsulation
})

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

**Advantage:**
You can directly override material class properties in the `sample-component.component.css` like:

```
.mat-tab-label {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 55px !important;
}

.mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: #0a4963;
}

/*** To change the arrow color ****/
.mat-select-arrow {
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(10, 73, 99);
}
```

**Method 2) Traditional way (without disabling encapsulation) (Avoid):**
**Advantage:** No change to be made in component
Change in `component.component.css` like:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 55px !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: #0a4963;
}

/*** To change the arrow color ****/
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  color: rgb(10, 73, 99);
}

/***    /deep/ too works   ****/
/deep/ .mat-select-arrow {
  color: rgb(10, 73, 99);
}
```

**DISADVANTAGE (A word of caution for Method 2):**
Angular is planning to drop support for ng-deep. There is [this recent conversation on git](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160) for the alternatives. Also it is indicated in the official angular site as `::ng-deep` is intended only for cushioning during the **[deprication support](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)**.

> Use /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep only with emulated view encapsulation. Emulated is the default and most commonly used view encapsulation. For more information, see the Controlling view encapsulation section.

**References:**
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Method 1 is super dangerous if you don't scope your overrides appropriately. Method 2 is deprecated.

Comment: No need to viewencapsulation to false. There should be at least one global style sheet you could include material overrides - no need for ng-deep at that point

Answer (score 2):

on this way you can change this mat-select element on your entire app:

create this file: mat-select.scss (or what ever name you want, but with scss extension)

( according to your file system stracture , for img/svg import), put this inside:

```
.mat-select-arrow-wrapper {
  background-image: url("./assets/chevron-down.svg");

 }

 .mat-select-arrow {
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

import your new scss file into styles.scss like that(according to your new file location):

@import './../mat-select';

smile

Answer (score 1):

As `ng::deep` is deprecated, and changing the encapsulation is not recommended, I suggest the following solution:

1) Add a class to **select**.

```
<mat-select class="my-class">
```

2) configure your preferences in **src/styles.scss**

```
.my-class .mat-select-arrow {
    // your preferences here.
}

.my-class .mat-select-arrow-wrapper {
    // your preferences here.
}
```

**See also:**

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.html#L15

Answer (score 0):

1)css change for .mat-select-arrow

```
.mat-select-arrow {
    border-left: unset !important;
    border-right: unset !important;
}
```

2)matSuffix to image/icon

```
 <mat-form-field class="input-field">
        <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
        <mat-select  formControlName="lableName" id="labelId" >
           <mat-option *ngFor="let m of DataObj[v].option" [value]="m">{{m}}
           </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <i matSuffix class="icon-down"></i>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried border image but border image can repeat itself. On safari browser, border image does not work well. The issue may persist in chrome as well.
Instead of border image, we should use background image on mat-arrow-wrapper class. Background image repeat property can be set to no-repeat and image can be set to center. This works well with both chrome and safari.

```
 :host ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow-wrapper {
  background-image: url('../../../assets/icons/anyimage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And we have to hide the default arrow. For that we can use border: none for mat-select-arrow. Also if you want to adjust your image to the left, increase the width on mat-select-arrow.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  border: none;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a chevron shaped icon is required this can be used to manipulate the exiting triangle shape to look like a chevron. I know this is not a general solution because the border-top colour needs to match the background of the input field but if all your select backgrounds is the same colour it will work fine.

```css
.mat-select-arrow {
    /* Remove the top part of the existing arrow triangle to form a chevron shape */
    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      margin-left: -3px;
      margin-top: -5px;
      border-left: 3px solid transparent;
      border-right: 3px solid transparent;
      border-top: 3px solid white; /* This needs to match your input field background */
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One more scenario,when we have multiple mat-select in the same page and different arrow styles are needed

then we can do like

> `:host ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow { display: none; }`

After you can use a class to place a background like this

```
.blackArrowDD {
  background: url("../../../../assets/images/downArrow.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 95%;
  background-size: 4%;
}
```

Then add the class to your mat-form-field

```
 <mat-form-field  class="blackArrowDD" appearance="fill">
```

Adjust the parameters of the background as per your form-field width

Answer (score 0):

first hide the arrow using following css.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  border: unset !important;
}
```

then use the `<mat-select-trigger>` to replace the icon.

```
<mat-select multiple>
            <mat-select-trigger>
              <i matSuffix class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let column of showHideColumns"
                        [disabled]="column.required"
                        [value]="column.id">
              {{column.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add the **border: none** style

```
.mat-select-arrow {
  ...
  border: none;
  ...
}
```

And try to change **width** and **height** properties. Because they have **0px** default value. If it will be needed.

Comment: My chrome doesn't like the 'icon' tag or the content of the 'content' tag, what are these?